# How to avoid stacking of jquery post()

Tags: jquery, post

I have a script that searches my site for duplicate content as a user is typing in the title of a new post (just like on Quora). Right now it fires off a post request on keyup, leading to stacking of post requests.

Any ideas on the best way to avoid this?

```
$("#topic_title").keyup(function(){
    var search_val=$(this).val(); 
    $.post('/?post_type=topic&duplicate=1',{s:search_val},function(data){
        if(data.length>0){
           var results = $(data).find( '#results' );
           $("#duplicates").html(results);
        }

     });
});
```

** Thanks for all of the quality answers! I went with the abort() method for simplicity. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things I will generally do in a situation like this:

1. Only send off the request after no key is pressed for a certain time period, say .5 a second.  This way if a person is typing quickly, you don't send off 10 requests, you just send one when they stop typing.  This can be done by using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.
2. When a new request is sent, cancel the previous.  This way there is only ever one active request.  You really only care about the latest anyway.  This can be done by using `abort()`.

A rough outline:

```
var timeout;
var xhr;

$("#topic_title").keyup(function(){
    if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    if(xhr) xhr.abort();

    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        doThePost(<parameters>);
    }, 500);
});

function doThePost(){
    xhr = $.post(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would throttle the keyup event to happen on every so often.
You could use this [throttle plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

Example here would throttle the event to fire with a lag of 250ms so instead of every key stroke only 1 keyup every 250ms:

```
 $("#topic_title").keyup($.throttle(250, function () {
      var search_val=$(this).val(); 
      $.post('/?post_type=topic&duplicate=1',{s:search_val},function(data){
         if(data.length>0){
            var results = $(data).find( '#results' );
            $("#duplicates").html(results);
         }
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery).

```
var xhr = null;

$("#topic_title").keyup(function()
{
    var search_val=$(this).val();

    if(xhr != null)
        xhr.abort();

    xhr = $.post('/?post_type=topic&duplicate=1',{s:search_val},function(data){
        if(data.length>0){
           var results = $(data).find( '#results' );
           $("#duplicates").html(results);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a timer and call the post and clear timer if it is stacked. See below,

```
$(function () { 
  var timer = null;//in scope
  $("#topic_title").keyup(function(){
    var search_val=$(this).val();

    if (timer != null) {
       clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
       $.post('/?post_type=topic&duplicate=1',{s:search_val},function(data){
          if(data.length>0){
            var results = $(data).find( '#results' );
            $("#duplicates").html(results);
          }      
       });
     }, 1000); //The timer is 1 second, update timer as your need.
  });
});
```

Comment: You can place `timer` inside of your ready function to avoid global variables.

Comment: @JamesMontagne isn't `clearTimeout` is executed in global scope?

Comment: Your call to `clearTimeout` will pass the value of the variable as a parameter.  As long as your call has access to the variable then you're good.

Comment: @JamesMontagne so dumb of me.. was thinking about something else and wrote it that way.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jQuery plugin.  [throttle-debounce.js](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)